# i am getting an error while writing an mysql query for deletin duplicate data in database

Tags: mysql

I tried the below code

```
 DELETE FROM `f` FROM 'exam' AS 'f' INNER JOIN 'exam' AS 'g' on
                  f.question=g.question any f.id<g.id;
```

to find duplicates in the database
so please make the required changes so that I can eliminate the error

Comment: post your error in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `any` to `and` and add `.*` to `f`:

```
DELETE f.* FROM `exam` f
INNER JOIN `exam` AS g 
on f.question=g.question
and f.id < g.id;
```